# Trouble debugging assembly code for greater of two numbers

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I wrote the following code to check if the 1st number- 'x' is greater than the 2nd number- 'y'. For `x>y` output should be `1` and for `x<=y` output should be `0`.

```
section .txt
    global _start
    global checkGreater

_start:
    mov rdi,x
    mov rsi,y

    call checkGreater 

    mov rax,60 
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
    
checkGreater:
    mov r8,rdi
    mov r9,rsi

    cmp r8,r9
    jg skip
    mov [c],byte '0'
    skip:
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,c
    mov rdx,1
    syscall
    
    ret

section .data
x db 7
y db 5
c db '1',0
```

But due to some reasons(of course from my end), the code always gives 0 as the output when executed.

I am using the following commands to run the code on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with nasm 2.14.02-1

```
nasm -f elf64 fileName.asm
ld -s -o fileName fileName.o
./fileName
```

**Where did I make a mistake?**

**And how should one debug assembly codes**, I looked for printing received arguments in checkGreater, but it turns out that's a disturbing headache itself.

Note: If someone wondering why I didn't directly use x and y in checkGreater, I want to extend the comparison to user inputs, and so wrote code in that way only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions

```
mov rdi,x
mov rsi,y
```

write the address of `x` into `rdi`, and of `y` into `rsi`. The further code then goes on to compare the addresses, which are always `x<y`, since `x` is defined above `y`.

What you should have written instead is

```
mov rdi,[x]
mov rsi,[y]
```

But then you have another problem: `x` and `y` variables are 1 byte long, while the destination registers are 8 bytes long. So simply doing the above fix will read extraneous bytes, leading to useless results. The final correction is to either fix the size of the variables (writing `dq` instead of `db`), or read them as bytes:

```
movzx rdi,byte [x]
movzx rsi,byte [y]
```

As for

> And how should one debug assembly codes

The main tool for you is an assembly-level debugger, like [EDB](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger) on Linux or [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com) on Windows. But in fact, most debuggers, even the ones intended for languages like C++, are capable of displaying disassembly for the program being debugged. So you can use e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), or even a GUI wrapper for it like Qt Creator or Eclipse. Just be sure to switch to machine code mode, or use the appropriate commands like GDB's `disassemble`, `stepi`, `info registers` etc..

Note that you don't have to build EDB or GDB from source (as the links above might suggest): they are likely already packaged in the Linux distribution you use. E.g. on Ubuntu the packages are called [`edb-debugger`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/devel/edb-debugger) and [`gdb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/devel/gdb).